# split the strings with space and comma and print this in a new line in php

Tags: php, string, file, replace

I need to split a string in php according to comma and space if the string length is greater than 33.

my code is below for write in to a text fle

```
$Address="Kuruva Islands,Mananthavady Kodanad"; 

fwrite($fo, str_repeat(" ",(33-strlen($Address))/2).$Address."\r\n");
```

It outputs like,

```
Palvelicham,
Mananthavady Kodanad
```

But I need the Output centre alligned like,

```
             Palvelicham,Mananthavady
                     Kodanad
```

and also i need to write it in to a text file..
please help.

Comment: Why would you need it? Do you use it in HTML?

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('/\s+/', '/\n/', trim($string));` ?

Answer (score 0):

And why would you use regex for that? To make it unnecessary complicated?

```
$address="Palvelicham,Mananthavady Kodanad";
$replaced = str_replace(" ", "\n", $address);
```

Output:

```
Palvelicham,Mananthavady
Kodanad
```

Comment: Thanks 'Y U NO WORK',but Here $address is not a static variable its dynamic. and also I need to write it in to a text file using fwrite(). I need it in to centre aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Haven't tested, but should work.

```
$str = 'Palvelicham,Mananthavady Kodanad';
$formated_str = implode('\r\n', explode(' ', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function for string length and use explode to split after space and comma..

```
function limit_text($text, $length) // Limit Text
{
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
    $stringCut = substr($text, 0, $length);
    $text = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
    }
    return $text;
}
```

explode syntax:

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function strlen() and str_replace(), like this:

```
$str = "Kuruva Islands,Mananthavady Kodanad";
if(strlen($str) > 33) { // If the string length is greater than 33
    $str = str_replace(" ", "\n", $str); // Replace the spaces by a new line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $result="";
        $stringinput = "Palvelicham,Mananthavady Kodanad";
        $arraystring = explode(" ", $stringinput);
        $arraystringcomma = new Array();
        foreach($arraystring as $item){
            $arraystringcomma = array_merge(arraystringcomma , explode(",", $stringinput));
        }
        $stringoutput = new Array();
        $i= 0;
        foreach($arraystringcomma as $item){
            if(strlen($stringoutput[$i] . $item)<=33){
                $stringoutput[$i] .= $item;
            }else{
                $i++;
                $stringoutput[$i] = $item;
            }
        }
        $result = implode("\n",$stringoutput);
```